# How to detect invalid user input in a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a batch file to ask for a password to continue, i have very simple code that works.

```
@echo off
:Begin
cls
echo.
echo Enter Password
set /p pass=
if %pass%==Password goto Start 

:Start
cls
echo What would you like me to do? (Date/Chrome/Lock/Shutdown/Close)
set /p task=
if %task%==Date goto Task=Date
if %task%==Chrome goto Task=Chrome
if %task%==Lock goto Task=Lock
if %task%==Shutdown goto Task=Shutdown
if %task%==Close goto Task=Close
```

I need to detect when the user entered an invalid password, i have spent an hour researching but i found nothing. I'm not advanced in any way so try and keep it very simple like the code above.

Please help me.

Comment: Labels in batch are simply place-markers. They do not "end a procedure" like Delphi or C. Like Assembler, batch simply charges on, so in your code, the label `Start` would be reached regardless of whether the password matched or not. Other correspondents' replies are also valid. Best to take them in combination.

Comment: For everyone reading this (I know this thread is old) A "Insert Password" Function in Batch is not recommended, as everyone executing it may just open it via Editor and just take it from there. It looks cool but offers no security at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing exactly one line of code!

```
@echo off
cls
:Begin
echo.
echo Enter Password
set /p pass=
if %pass%==Password goto Start 
cls
Echo %pass% is not the PASSWORD
goto :Begin

:Start
cls
echo What would you like me to do? (Date/Chrome/Lock/Shutdown/Close)
set /p task=
if %task%==Date goto Task=Date
if %task%==Chrome goto Task=Chrome
if %task%==Lock goto Task=Lock
if %task%==Shutdown goto Task=Shutdown
if %task%==Close goto Task=Close
```

If the password is invalid the code will simply continue to the next line which now is `goto :Begin`. This will restart the sequence. I changed the order around a bit so that the screen was cleared as well and the error was printed.

Comment: When i type in the wrong password, it goes back to :Begin but it doesn't echo the error message.

Comment: The `CLS` at the beginning clears the screen so you don't see the message.  You can remove it or insert a `pause` command after the echo.  Also consider using quotes as in `if "%pass%"=="Password" goto Start` which will avoid issues when the input is blank or if two words are entered.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to [Monacraft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886072), but using if-else statements:

```
@echo off
cls
:Begin
echo.
echo Enter Password
set /p pass=
if %pass%==Password (goto Start) else *echo Invalid password. && goto :Begin)

:Start
cls
echo What would you like me to do? (Date/Chrome/Lock/Shutdown/Close)
set /p task=
if %task%==Date goto Task=Date
if %task%==Chrome goto Task=Chrome
if %task%==Lock goto Task=Lock
if %task%==Shutdown goto Task=Shutdown
if %task%==Close goto Task=Close
```

What this does is it checks for the correct password. If it isn't the correct password, it will display an error message and go back to `:Begin`, which restarts the sequence.